# CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess error

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm working with CefSharp37 and I have a little problem.
I make a webapp in C# that use CefSharp and it works. All is ok.

When I change the pc were the app is playing it shut down.
The error is "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess is closed".

In the debug.log I find an error:

```
[0219/152816:WARNING:resource_bundle.cc(286)] locale_file_path.empty()
[0219/152816:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(148)] 000000001CBC1600: set chrome proxy config service to 000000001CBC1780
[0219/152816:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(277)] 000000001CBC1600: Done pushing proxy to UpdateProxyConfig
**[0219/152819:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(402)] Failed to establish GPU channel.**
[0219/152819:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(50)] Could not get the download directory.
```

Can you help me please?
What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Does the machine your having problems with by chance have an Intel graphics card? They are known to be problematic, `CEF` and therefore `CefSharp` don't have any fancy workarounds to disable features based on computer hardware like Chrome does.

The FAQ has some info regarding Graphics issues see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#troubleshooting-graphics-video-or-performance-problems

Comment: The problem was dll. I miss some dll.